# Do not have right aruguements and getting an error

Tags: django

Error - >>> expected string or bytes-like object

I have know idea about what is wrong in this

models.py ->>

```
      publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now =True, auto_now_add =  False, null =True)
      timestamp = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True, )
      updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now =True)
```

Comment: You need to show the actual error message and the full traceback. The error is not coming from this code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` together.

```
publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now =True, null =True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True )
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both auto_now and auto_now_add as they are mutually exclusive.

```
publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now =True, null =True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField( auto_now = True, )
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now =True)
```